# Could hackers steal dlls from an Azure Website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Asp.net MVC website that is hosted in Azure Websites. It uses dlls to access databases etc.

Can hackers potentially download those dlls?

Comment: Hackers can potentially do anything

Answer (score 4):

No, dll files in the bin folder can't be downloaded. The web server excludes certain file types and folders for download.

A hacker could of course potentially get the files, but he would have to hack into the server and access them as files directly, it can't just be done by downloading them.

Answer (score 0):

Basically: no.

Of course, if you open up the web site permissions, and move DLLs to places they should not be, etc - all bets are off.